# Windows CMD: How to recursively delete folder using a pattern

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is my command in linux console:

```
rm -rf `find . -name ".attributes"`
```

Note that .attributes is a folder. I wonder if there's an equivalent command or batch script in windows.

Comment: Open up a cmd prompt and type: `RD /?`.

Comment: And TBF, _although off topic_, your linux `shell` command should probably read, either, `find . -name ".attributes" -type d -print0|xargs -0 rm -r --` or `find . -name ".attributes" -type d -exec rm -r {} +`, _you can still include the `-f`orce option too, if needed_.